# distributed deployment of wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2

I have followed the procedure for cluster deployment of wso2 API manager mentioned in

Referencing: http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager

But when i am running API manager with different profile wso2 API manager is started but is not accessible from the browser.However, if I change the port offset in carbon.xml to 0 and then r everything runs fine.Please tell me where is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the port offset in carbon.xml, all [default port](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products) values will be adjusted according to the port offset values.

If port offset is 2, the default HTTPS port 9443 will be changed 9445 in the run time. So you should access the management console via 9445 port.

Also see following wiki page about changing port offset for API Manager.

http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset

I hope this helps

Comment: i am accessing via the link that is shown on the console itself.

Comment: In addition I also want that if a particular profile is invoked for eg. publisher then on the main url /store should not work.

Comment: From your question, I understood that you could access the API Manager without a port offset. That's why I mentioned about port offset. When you start APIM with profiles, you can still access other web applications. However those will not function properly. This is a known issue with profiles. http://wso2.com/mailarchive/dev/2013-September/022818.html

Comment: @user3189802 For that, you have to manually delete the unwanted app from APIM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/. For ex. if you don't want the store app then delete the store app from the said location.